# Modal with reacjs is getting null value

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a parent like this:

```
function ViewBudgetPage() {
  const pathname = useParams();
  const [plate, setPlate] = useState("");
  const [bikeDataModal, setBikeDataModal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getBudgetByIdRequest(pathname.id).then((response) => {
      setPlate(response.data.plate);
    });
  }, [pathname.id]);

  function openBikeDataModal() {
    setBikeDataModal(true);
  }

  function closeBikeDataModal() {
    setBikeDataModal(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="text-center mt-5">
        <input type="text" defaultValue={plate} disabled className="me-3" />
        <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={openBikeDataModal}>
          Click Me
        </button>
      <BikeDataModal
        show={bikeDataModal}
        close={closeBikeDataModal}
        plate={plate}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default ViewBudgetPage;
```

I get the plate data in the useEffect and set it to the value.
The plate value is being passed to the modal.
The modal open only on click.
Inside the modal class I have another useEffect that uses the plate value in a backend request.
When first rendering the plate value is null and I get error from backend, after that I get the right values.
[image]
How to make my modal get the right plate value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are calling `GET /listBikeByPlate` endpoint in `BikeDataModal` component.

If that is the case, the problem is that you are rendering the `BikeDataModal` when `plate` is still `undefined`/`null`, consequently calling `GET /listBikeByPlate` with no value for your query parameter `plate` (according to the `?plate=` in screenshot)

So the best thing you can do is to avoid rendering the child component until the initial request in `useEffect` has been finished.

My suggestion is to add a new state like so

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
```

And then inside of your `getBudgetByIdRequest`, set `setIsFetching` to `true` once the fetch is resolved/finished like so

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getBudgetByIdRequest(pathname.id).then((response) => {
      setPlate(response.data.plate);
      setIsLoaded(true)
    });
  }, [pathname.id]);
```

And finally do the conditional rendering right before your original `return` block

```
if (!isLoaded) {
  return <>Loading</>
}
```

So after the fetch is finished and your `plate` has been set, your `BikeDataModal` will now have the correct `plate` data, making the correct API call.

In conclusion, you full code should be

```
function ViewBudgetPage() {
    const pathname = useParams()
    const [plate, setPlate] = useState('')
    const [bikeDataModal, setBikeDataModal] = useState(false)
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        getBudgetByIdRequest(pathname.id).then((response) => {
            setPlate(response.data.plate)
            setIsLoaded(true)
        })
    }, [pathname.id])

    function openBikeDataModal() {
        setBikeDataModal(true)
    }

    function closeBikeDataModal() {
        setBikeDataModal(false)
    }

    if (!isLoaded) return <>Loading</>

    return (
        <div className="text-center mt-5">
            <input type="text" defaultValue={plate} disabled className="me-3" />
            <button className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={openBikeDataModal}>
                Click Me
            </button>
            <BikeDataModal show={bikeDataModal} close={closeBikeDataModal} plate={plate} />
        </div>
    )
}
export default ViewBudgetPage
```